# Birthday attack to find near collision

Tags: collision-resistance

Follow up on this question: [How efficient are the generic attacks regarding near-collision-resistance?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/42694/how-efficient-are-the-generic-attacks-regarding-near-collision-resistance?noredirect=1&lq=1)

> Let $H:\{0,1\}^∗→\{0,1\}^n$ be a cryptographically secure hash function. Let $k\in \mathbb{N}$ be $0 \leq k \leq n$. Without further details, how much effort is needed to find two strings $x_1,x_2$ such that $\Delta(H(x_1),H(x_2))\leq k$ holds? $\Delta(\cdot,\cdot)$ denote the hamming distance.

The accepted answer mentioned that it requires $\displaystyle \sqrt \frac{1}{p}$ hashes where $p=\displaystyle \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{k}{n\choose i}}{2^n}$ to have probability of $1/2$ to obtain one near collision pair. Why is that?

I tried to work out the math using birthday paradox. I get the minimum number of hashes one has to compute is something like:

$$\frac{2^{n/2}}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^k{n\choose i}\cdot 2^i}}$$

Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: The lower and the upper equation are exactly the same.

Comment: almost the same right. The upper doesn't have $2^i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so let's go from start to finish on this.

Note that for a hash function we can model the output bits as independent binary variables and thus apply a [binomial distribution model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) to find out how many bits take a certain value. So the Probability that $k$ bits don't match is $\binom{n}{k}2^{-(n-k)}2^{-k}=\binom{n}k2^{-n}$ (intuitively we aggregate all possible allowed missmatches here). Now we want that *at most* $k$ bits don't match and thus we can sum: $\sum^k_{i=0}\binom{n}i2^{-n}$. Now note that $2^{-n}$ is a constant factor and thus $p=\sum^k_{i=0}\binom{n}i2^{-n}=2^{-n}\sum^k_{i=0}\binom{n}i=\frac{\sum^k_{i=0}\binom{n}i}{2^n}$, now finally we can use said birthday argument to find the number of messages needed to be $\sqrt{\frac1p}=\sqrt{\frac1{\frac{\sum^k_{i=0}\binom{n}i}{2^n}}}=\sqrt{\frac{2^n}{\sum^k_{i=0}\binom{n}i}}=\frac{2^{n/2}}{\sqrt{\sum^k_{i=0}\binom{n}i}}$ which is the expected result.

Note as mentioned in [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/48156/23623), this result can be proven more rigourously as well, which was done in [*"Memoryless Near-Collisions via Coding Theory" by Mario Lamberger, Florian Mendel, Vincent Rijmen and Koen Simoens (PDF)*](https://online.tugraz.at/tug_online/voe_main2.getvolltext?pCurrPk=55825).